# HashTable passing value is Interface?

Tags: java, collections, parameters, interface, hashtable

i saw some code where HashTable(collection) value is passed as interface

```
public class Channels {

    private static final Hashtable<String, IChannel> channels =
        new Hashtable<String, IChannel>();

    public void putChannel(String serviceChannelName, IChannel channel) {
        channels.put(serviceChannelName, channel);
    }
}
```

like

```
public interface IChannel {

    public void start();

    public void stop();
}
```

what exectly going to use and and how it can possible to pass interface object (while we can not create interface object.?? please help me

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial on interfaces - this is just one example of using them, but once you've got the bigger picture, everything will make more sense. Basically, you're not passing an "interface object" - you're passing a reference to an object which is an instance of some class which *implements* the interface.

Comment: "to pass interface object" You have to use a class that implements IChannel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass instances of concrete type, which implements `IChannel` interface.

Example:

Definition of concrete type:

```
public class ChannelImpl implements IChannel {
    public void start() { 
        /* implementation here */ 
    }

    public void stop() { 
        /* implementation here */ 
    }
}
```

and then use your implementation:

```
new Channels().put("Channel1", new ChannelImpl());
```

To learn how to use this, you should read about OOP.

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing an interface object, but an **interface implementation**, which gives you room to put different implementations of the interface to the map.